# Open socket connections on Hadoop datanode on CentOS

Tags: sockets, hadoop, centos, cloudera

I am running a sample hadoop job on my centos 6.2.64 machine for debugging,

```
hadoop jar hadoop-examples-0.20.2-cdh3u3.jar randomtextwriter o
```

and it appears that after the job is completed, the connections to datanodes still remain.

```
java       8979 username   51u     IPv6          326596025        0t0       TCP localhost:50010->localhost:56126 (ESTABLISHED)
java       8979 username   54u     IPv6          326621990        0t0       TCP localhost:50010->localhost:56394 (ESTABLISHED)
java       8979 username   59u     IPv6          326578719        0t0       TCP *:50010 (LISTEN)
java       8979 username   75u     IPv6          326596390        0t0       TCP localhost:50010->localhost:56131 (ESTABLISHED)
java       8979 username   84u     IPv6          326621621        0t0       TCP localhost:50010->localhost:56388 (ESTABLISHED)
java       8979 username   85u     IPv6          326622171        0t0       TCP localhost:50010->localhost:56395 (ESTABLISHED)
java       9276 username   77u     IPv6          326621714        0t0       TCP localhost:56388->localhost:50010 (ESTABLISHED)
java       9276 username   78u     IPv6          326596118        0t0       TCP localhost:56126->localhost:50010 (ESTABLISHED)
java       9408 username   75u     IPv6          326596482        0t0       TCP localhost:56131->localhost:50010 (ESTABLISHED)
java       9408 username   76u     IPv6          326622170        0t0       TCP localhost:56394->localhost:50010 (ESTABLISHED)
java       9408 username   77u     IPv6          326622930        0t0       TCP localhost:56395->localhost:50010 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Eventually I get this error in the datanode logs after sometime.

```
2012-04-12 15:56:29,151 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(127.0.0.1:50010, storageID=DS-591618896-176.9.25.36-50010-1333654003291, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020):DataXceiver
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/hadoop-serendio/dfs/data/current/subdir4/blk_-4401902756916730461_31251.meta (Too many open files)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.FSDataset.getMetaDataInputStream(FSDataset.java:996)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockSender.<init>(BlockSender.java:125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.readBlock(DataXceiver.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:163)
```

This leads to issues in the production system, namely datanode running out of xcievers.
This behaviour does not seem to happen on my Ubuntu development box. We are using cloudera hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u3 for our purposes.

Any pointers to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add in hdfs-site.xml if you have not specified yet:

```
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.max.xcievers</name>
<value>4096</value>
</property>
```

defalut is 256 i think....

this the formaula type calculation for how much xciever you should have to avoid such error...

```
 # of xcievers = (( # of storfiles + # of regions * 4 + # of regioServer * 2 ) / # of datanodes)+reserves(20%)
```

Comment: try incresing your ulimit value